# console.log() printing undefined on the console

Tags: javascript, reactjs

my applicants.js

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./Applicant.css";
import axios from "axios";
import Applicant from "./Applicant";
const URL = "http://localhost:5000/applicants";
const fetchHandler = async () => {
  return await axios.get(URL).then((res) => res.data);
};
const Applicants = () => {
  const [applicants, setApplicant] = useState();
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchHandler().then((data) => setApplicant(data.applicants));
  }, []);
  console.log(applicants);
  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        {applicants &&
          applicants.map((applicant, i) => (
            <li key={i}>
              <Applicant applicant={applicant} />
            </li>
          ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Applicants;
```

**In the console the output is:
undefined                                    applicants.js**

there is no other error in the console only this one.
i'm using react v6

Comment: This is expected. Your `useEffect()` callback only triggers after the initial render. On the first render, your state is `undefined` as you haven't passed an initial value to `useState()`

Comment: Are you sure about using React 6? The current version of React is 18. You might be probably using React Router 6.

Comment: All the dependencies                                           "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"

Comment: @AyubAli `"react": "^18.2.0"` means you're using React v18.2, not 6. `react-router-dom": "^6.3.0"` means you're using react-router-dom v6.3

Answer (score 1):

useEffect is working as compomentDidMount with [] (that means passing without any dependency) and you are trying to print before its running at that time state is undefined

Answer (score 0):

`setState()` runs asynchronously in a queue based system. Therefore if you want to update a state, this update will be piled up on the system queue.

However, you can check if data has been loaded

```
  const [applicants, setApplicant] = useState();
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchHandler().then((data) => {
       const newApplicants = data.applicants
       setApplicant(data.applicants);
       console.log(newApplicants) // returns data
       console.log(applicants) // returns undefined but in the final state it will contain the data
    })
  }, []);
```

Comment: i modified the code but i got this error                                                                                             ERROR in ./src/components/Applicant/Applicants.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
SyntaxError: C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\BOOK STORE101\frontend\src\components\Applicant\Applicants.js: Unexpected token (16:4)

  14 |   useEffect(() => {
  15 |     fetchHandler().then((data) =>
> 16 |     const newApplicants = data.applicants
     |     ^

Comment: @AyubAli small typo, sorry about that. Updated the code. please check if it works (: